# NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a @link.user but it keeps giving me this 'undefined method' error.

```
    irb(main):002:0> @link.user
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
>           from (irb):2
>           from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in`
>   start'
>           from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in
>   `start'
>           from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in`console'
>           from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
>           from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`
>   '
>           from bin/rails:4:in `require'
>           from bin/rails:4:in`'

**My user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
            :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

     has_many :links
 end
```

**My link.rb**

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    def show
    end

end
```

Comment: it seems like you're trying to check the value of an instance variable from the rails console that hasn't been set. Perhaps you should try creating a new link object from the rails console and saving it into a variable to then check that it is correctly associated. For example: 'user = User.first' (assuming you already have a user in your database..if not create one) Then to create the link use `user.links.create!(link_params)` You'll have to pass in the specific parameters for your model where it says 'link_params'

Comment: @link is nil, how are you instantiating that variable ?

Answer (score 0):

`@link` all by itself is just an unspecified instance variable and will always be `nil` so `@link.anything` will give you `undefined method 'anything' for nil:Nilclass`

Set @link to contain something first.

```
@link = Link.new
```

`@link.user` will then work, although it will be nil as you haven't yet assigned a user to the Link object.

Comment: and how would I say assign the user to the link object/file?

Comment: If it's the current user... `@link.user = current_user`

Answer (score 0):

Let me know what is in @link object.
Below are some suggestion for your issue

- First, You have records in user table and link table in your database
  with your   proper association.
- Check You have user_id in link table
- Create user with two or thee records of links

For Example,

```
@user = User.create(name: "foram")
```

Now, create links with user, For Example

```
@user.links.create(comment: "something in comment")
```

You can check in console for user has links or links related to which user

```
@user.links(@user which has one record from user table)
@link.user(@link which has one record from link table)
```

For association in rails refer below link.
[Rails Assoiciations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)